# How is printf printing 53 digits after decimal point?

Tags: c++, precision

I was trying to print the square root of a number at some given precision.

```cpp
int N;
int precision;
cin>>N>>precision;
printf("%.*lf",precision,std::sqrt(N));
```

and this is what clang++ printed out:

```
%./a.out
2 100
1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It was able to print over 50 digits of precision?
I thought doubles could only handle 17 digits?

I'm running clang++ on apple silicon m1

Comment: Resolution is not precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the set of 64-bit floating-point values, `sqrt(2)` is closest to the floating-point value that **exactly** corresponds to the fraction `6369051672525773/4503599627370496`. It's this rational number, or `1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125` in decimal, that `printf()` is printing with as much precision as you tell it to.

The 17-digit limit refers to the number of significant decimal digits required to distinguish any two floating-point numbers. In other words, if you print a floating-point number with 17 significant digits of precision, and read it back, you are guaranteed to get the same floating-point number (to the last bit) as the one you started with.

The conversion in the other direction, where you start with a decimal number, convert it into floating-point (i.e. approximate it to the closest fraction with a 53-bit numerator and a power-of-two denominator), and then display it as decimal, only guarantees to preserve 15 decimal digits. For example, the decimal number `0.1234567890123456789` will be approximated to `8895999183877727/72057594037927936`, which is `0.12345678901234567736988623209981597028672695159912109375`. In this case the first 17 digits (counting from `1`) of the printed floating-point value correspond to the original number.

Comment: Re “The 17-digit limit refers to the number of significant digits that you can convert into 64-bit floating point…” The number of significant digits for which it is guaranteed that a round-trip decimal→double→decimal with correct round-to-nearest reproduces the original number is 15. 17 is the number of decimal digits needed to guarantee that a round-trip double→decimal→double reproduces the original number. (And this is why we want `printf` to be able to print at least 17 digits correctly: It guarantees we can reproduce the original `double` from the printed output.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point, thanks for bringing it up. I've now amended the answer to distinguish between the two kinds of round trips.

Answer (score 3):

> It was able to print over 50 digits of precision? I thought doubles could only handle 17 digits?

It's false precision because you asked for it.

Say I ask someone how tall a building is and they say "oh, about 50 meters". If you ask me to give that to you in feet to five decimal places, I can -- 164.04199 feet. But the precision is false.

Check it out:
Output: 1.414213562373095145474621858738828450441...
Correct: 1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569...